# Eclipse EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION crash

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, jvm

Today at work my eclipse started to crash repeatedly. It is enough to open it and start editing files to have a crash after few minutes. I reinstalled everything: Eclipse, Workspace, Java but nothing helped. Please try to identify the source of my problems as I am currently unable to work.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005789c8df, pid=1192, tid=0x0000000000002370
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x4bc8df]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000015363800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9072, stack(0x0000000016830000,0x0000000016930000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000008

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x000000001859b620, RDX=0x0000000000002000
RSP=0x000000001692bd10, RBP=0x000000001f5e3e98, RSI=0x000000001859b620, RDI=0x000000001692c240
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000019c4abc0, R10=0x000000001692c240, R11=0x0000000021122f20
R12=0x000000001e818510, R13=0x000000001faa9090, R14=0x000000001692bdf8, R15=0x000000001692be18
RIP=0x000000005789c8df, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001692bd10)
0x000000001692bd10:   000000001f5e41d0 000000001f5e3e98
0x000000001692bd20:   000000001859b620 000000001692c240
0x000000001692bd30:   000000001f5e3e98 000000001692be68
0x000000001692bd40:   000000000000000c 000000005789e0f9
0x000000001692bd50:   000000001f5e41d0 00000000000003f3
0x000000001692bd60:   0000000000000001 00000000185a2ec0
0x000000001692bd70:   000000001692cc18 00000000578d0b90
0x000000001692bd80:   0000000020c00e60 000000001419db40
0x000000001692bd90:   000000001ab0db30 000000001692bec0
0x000000001692bda0:   000000001419db40 000000000000000e
0x000000001692bdb0:   000000001692c240 000000005789fe83
0x000000001692bdc0:   000000001692c240 0000000000000001
0x000000001692bdd0:   0000000000000001 000000001692be68
0x000000001692bde0:   0000000020c00eb0 0000000020c08e48
0x000000001692bdf0:   00000000000b01d0 000000001419db40
0x000000001692be00:   0000000000000400 00000000202de650 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000005789c8df)
0x000000005789c8bf:   4c 89 64 24 50 4c 8b e0 4c 3b e8 0f 84 4f 01 00
0x000000005789c8cf:   00 44 8b 43 28 4c 8b 8f f8 09 00 00 4b 8b 1c c1
0x000000005789c8df:   48 8b 43 08 48 83 38 00 75 2a 8b 57 28 0f 1f 40
0x000000005789c8ef:   00 8b 43 28 3b c2 73 0c 8b c8 48 8b 47 30 48 8b 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000001859b620 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000002000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001692bd10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015363800
RBP=0x000000001f5e3e98 is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000001859b620 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000001692c240 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015363800
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000019c4abc0 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000001692c240 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015363800
R11=0x0000000021122f20 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000001e818510 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000001faa9090 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000001692bdf8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015363800
R15=0x000000001692be18 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015363800


Stack: [0x0000000016830000,0x0000000016930000],  sp=0x000000001692bd10,  free space=1007k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x4bc8df]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4be0f9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4bfe83]
V  [jvm.dll+0x471e35]
V  [jvm.dll+0x472b94]
V  [jvm.dll+0x455b42]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa50a2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa59df]
V  [jvm.dll+0x244314]
V  [jvm.dll+0x29b34a]
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21d9f]
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21e3b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x159bd]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2a2e1]


Current CompileTask:
C2:  40215 12282       4       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::decodeType (1094 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001e772000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7316, stack(0x0000000029240000,0x0000000029340000)]
  0x0000000019b57000 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=1664, stack(0x0000000027010000,0x0000000027110000)]
  0x0000000019b52800 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2028, stack(0x00000000262a0000,0x00000000263a0000)]
  0x0000000019b50800 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=7492, stack(0x00000000259d0000,0x0000000025ad0000)]
  0x0000000019b51800 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=6652, stack(0x00000000256b0000,0x00000000257b0000)]
  0x0000000019b50000 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=8776, stack(0x00000000255b0000,0x00000000256b0000)]
  0x0000000019b4f000 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3528, stack(0x0000000025480000,0x0000000025580000)]
  0x0000000019b4d800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7084, stack(0x0000000024540000,0x0000000024640000)]
  0x0000000019b4d000 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=4328, stack(0x0000000023e40000,0x0000000023f40000)]
  0x0000000019b4b800 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=7632, stack(0x0000000023580000,0x0000000023680000)]
  0x0000000019b4a800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7444, stack(0x0000000023080000,0x0000000023180000)]
  0x0000000019b4a000 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3988, stack(0x000000001d250000,0x000000001d350000)]
  0x0000000019b49000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6260, stack(0x000000001cab0000,0x000000001cbb0000)]
  0x0000000019b47800 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=8460, stack(0x000000001c2a0000,0x000000001c3a0000)]
  0x000000001881f800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=9044, stack(0x000000001a970000,0x000000001aa70000)]
  0x00000000174c2000 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2552, stack(0x0000000019260000,0x0000000019360000)]
  0x0000000017e53000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1208, stack(0x0000000018e60000,0x0000000018f60000)]
  0x00000000173b5800 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=388, stack(0x0000000018d60000,0x0000000018e60000)]
  0x0000000017dc5800 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6220, stack(0x0000000018c60000,0x0000000018d60000)]
  0x000000001725a000 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=4456, stack(0x0000000017a90000,0x0000000017b90000)]
  0x00000000153f8000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4200, stack(0x0000000016c30000,0x0000000016d30000)]
  0x0000000015384000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3504, stack(0x0000000016b30000,0x0000000016c30000)]
  0x0000000015372000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8264, stack(0x0000000016a30000,0x0000000016b30000)]
  0x000000001536a800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2212, stack(0x0000000016930000,0x0000000016a30000)]
=>0x0000000015363800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9072, stack(0x0000000016830000,0x0000000016930000)]
  0x0000000015360000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4992, stack(0x0000000016730000,0x0000000016830000)]
  0x000000001535f000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8968, stack(0x0000000016630000,0x0000000016730000)]
  0x000000001419c800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8008, stack(0x0000000016460000,0x0000000016560000)]
  0x0000000015313800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9060, stack(0x0000000016360000,0x0000000016460000)]
  0x00000000025bd800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5840, stack(0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000015312000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000016260000,0x0000000016360000] [id=6856]
  0x000000001541e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000016d30000,0x0000000016e30000] [id=7232]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 137216K, used 28723K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 104448K, 8% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f5e7dd58,0x00000000fbb80000)
  from space 32768K, 59% used [0x00000000fbb80000,0x00000000fce8efd8,0x00000000fdb80000)
  to   space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000fe000000,0x00000000fe000000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 296448K, used 211965K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 296448K, 71% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000eceff748,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 79542K, capacity 86670K, committed 86912K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 9251K, capacity 11265K, committed 11392K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011cf0000,0x0000000011e00000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000115f0000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000057bf64f0
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000126b0000, 0x0000000012eb0000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000012eb0000, 0x00000000136b0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000002560000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=36682Kb max_used=36682Kb free=209077Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002930000, 0x0000000004d50000, 0x0000000011930000]
 total_blobs=10538 nmethods=9685 adapters=761
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 40.188 Thread 0x0000000015384000 12305       2       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment::askForType (113 bytes)
Event: 40.188 Thread 0x0000000015384000 nmethod 12305 0x0000000003bc4850 code [0x0000000003bc4a00, 0x0000000003bc4d88]
Event: 40.188 Thread 0x0000000015384000 12307       1       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.TypeParameter::getElementName (5 bytes)
Event: 40.188 Thread 0x0000000015384000 nmethod 12307 0x0000000003bbeb10 code [0x0000000003bbec60, 0x0000000003bbed70]
Event: 40.188 Thread 0x0000000015384000 12308       2       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding::canBeSeenBy (354 bytes)
Event: 40.189 Thread 0x0000000015384000 nmethod 12308 0x0000000003bc3350 code [0x0000000003bc3640, 0x0000000003bc40c8]
Event: 40.189 Thread 0x0000000015384000 12309       2       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope::getJavaLangEnum (24 bytes)
Event: 40.189 Thread 0x0000000015384000 nmethod 12309 0x0000000003bc2ed0 code [0x0000000003bc3040, 0x0000000003bc3228]
Event: 40.189 Thread 0x0000000015384000 12310       2       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope::getType (22 bytes)
Event: 40.189 Thread 0x0000000015384000 nmethod 12310 0x0000000003bc2a10 code [0x0000000003bc2b80, 0x0000000003bc2d78]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 26.671 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=55 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 131072K, used 102112K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 93184K, 100% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fb080000,0x00000000fb080000)
  from space 37888K, 23% used [0x00000000fb080000,0x00000000fb938000,0x00000000fd580000)
  to   space 36864K, 0% used [0x00000000fdc00000,0x00000000fdc00000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 230400K, used 206517K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000ee100000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 230400K, 89% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ec9ad508,0x00000000ee100000)
 Metaspace       used 76287K, capacity 83158K, committed 83456K, reserved 1122304K
  class space    used 9018K, capacity 10972K, committed 11008K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 26.701 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=55 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 133632K, used 17334K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000ffd00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 99840K, 0% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fb700000)
  from space 33792K, 51% used [0x00000000fdc00000,0x00000000feced888,0x00000000ffd00000)
  to   space 35840K, 0% used [0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fda00000)
 ParOldGen       total 230400K, used 213509K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000ee100000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 230400K, 92% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ed081508,0x00000000ee100000)
 Metaspace       used 76287K, capacity 83158K, committed 83456K, reserved 1122304K
  class space    used 9018K, capacity 10972K, committed 11008K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 28.622 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=56 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 133632K, used 117174K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000ffd00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 99840K, 100% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fb700000)
  from space 33792K, 51% used [0x00000000fdc00000,0x00000000feced888,0x00000000ffd00000)
  to   space 35840K, 0% used [0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fda00000)
 ParOldGen       total 230400K, used 213509K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000ee100000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 230400K, 92% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ed081508,0x00000000ee100000)
 Metaspace       used 77524K, capacity 84418K, committed 84608K, reserved 1122304K
  class space    used 9129K, capacity 11071K, committed 11136K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 28.668 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=56 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 135680K, used 11506K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 99840K, 0% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fb700000)
  from space 35840K, 32% used [0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fc23cad8,0x00000000fda00000)
  to   space 34304K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 230400K, used 230169K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000ee100000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 230400K, 99% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ee0c6450,0x00000000ee100000)
 Metaspace       used 77524K, capacity 84418K, committed 84608K, reserved 1122304K
  class space    used 9129K, capacity 11071K, committed 11136K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 28.668 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=57 (full 6):
 PSYoungGen      total 135680K, used 11506K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 99840K, 0% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fb700000)
  from space 35840K, 32% used [0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fc23cad8,0x00000000fda00000)
  to   space 34304K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 230400K, used 230169K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000ee100000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 230400K, 99% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ee0c6450,0x00000000ee100000)
 Metaspace       used 77524K, capacity 84418K, committed 84608K, reserved 1122304K
  class space    used 9129K, capacity 11071K, committed 11136K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 29.399 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=57 (full 6):
 PSYoungGen      total 135680K, used 0K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 99840K, 0% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fb700000)
  from space 35840K, 0% used [0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fda00000)
  to   space 34304K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 296448K, used 211949K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 296448K, 71% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ecefb748,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 77524K, capacity 84418K, committed 84608K, reserved 1122304K
  class space    used 9129K, capacity 11071K, committed 11136K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 30.216 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=58 (full 6):
 PSYoungGen      total 135680K, used 99840K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 99840K, 100% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fb700000)
  from space 35840K, 0% used [0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fb700000,0x00000000fda00000)
  to   space 34304K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 296448K, used 211949K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 296448K, 71% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ecefb748,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 78720K, capacity 85614K, committed 86016K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 9187K, capacity 11169K, committed 11264K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 30.224 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=58 (full 6):
 PSYoungGen      total 135168K, used 15343K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000ffb80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 104448K, 0% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fbb80000)
  from space 30720K, 49% used [0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fec7be00,0x00000000ffb80000)
  to   space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000fbb80000,0x00000000fbb80000,0x00000000fdb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 296448K, used 211957K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 296448K, 71% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ecefd748,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 78720K, capacity 85614K, committed 86016K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 9187K, capacity 11169K, committed 11264K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 40.143 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=59 (full 6):
 PSYoungGen      total 135168K, used 119791K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000ffb80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 104448K, 100% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fbb80000,0x00000000fbb80000)
  from space 30720K, 49% used [0x00000000fdd80000,0x00000000fec7be00,0x00000000ffb80000)
  to   space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000fbb80000,0x00000000fbb80000,0x00000000fdb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 296448K, used 211957K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 296448K, 71% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ecefd748,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 79510K, capacity 86670K, committed 86912K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 9251K, capacity 11265K, committed 11392K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 40.154 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=59 (full 6):
 PSYoungGen      total 137216K, used 19515K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 104448K, 0% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000fbb80000)
  from space 32768K, 59% used [0x00000000fbb80000,0x00000000fce8efd8,0x00000000fdb80000)
  to   space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000fe000000,0x00000000fe000000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 296448K, used 211965K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 296448K, 71% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000eceff748,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 79510K, capacity 86670K, committed 86912K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 9251K, capacity 11265K, committed 11392K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 39.350 Thread 0x0000000019b50000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000047618ac method=org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.DeadlockDetector.lockAcquired(Ljava/lang/Thread;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/ISchedulingRule;)V @ 139
Event: 39.351 Thread 0x0000000019b50000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000042a07f0 method=org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.DeadlockDetector.lockReleased(Ljava/lang/Thread;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/ISchedulingRule;)V @ 157
Event: 39.351 Thread 0x0000000019b50000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000475f700 method=org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.DeadlockDetector.reduceGraph(ILorg/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/ISchedulingRule;)V @ 37
Event: 39.357 Thread 0x00000000025bd800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000441e684 method=org.eclipse.jface.text.CopyOnWriteTextStore.getLength()I @ 4
Event: 39.411 Thread 0x00000000025bd800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004b05c40 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeToken(I)V @ 1056
Event: 39.458 Thread 0x00000000025bd800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003da7530 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse()V @ 107
Event: 40.073 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004464244 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.checkComment()V @ 266
Event: 40.107 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004d119ec method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.pushLineSeparator()V @ 33
Event: 40.107 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004461a08 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.pushLineSeparator()V @ 228
Event: 40.108 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004b03b94 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeToken(I)V @ 1821

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 40.184 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000f5c47528) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 40.184 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000f5c47a88) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 40.184 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000f5c48000) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 40.184 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000f5c48588) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 40.184 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000f5c48ad0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 40.184 Thread 0x0000000019b57000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000f5c49040) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
```

(...)

```
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -Xms40m -Xmx512m -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Ant\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;c:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\CryptoTech\CryptoCard\;C:\Program Files\CryptoTech\CryptoCard\;C:\Program Files\eclipse;
USERNAME=kurbanek
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23418)

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 16661736k(11725492k free), swap 33321612k(27961528k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_92-b14), built on Mar 31 2016 21:03:04 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Fri Jul 29 18:20:19 2016
elapsed time: 40 seconds (0d 0h 0m 40s)
```

Comment: Try updating your JRE, if that does not work, try a different IDE like IntelliJ or NetBeans.

Comment: Have you configured the location of your JDK in `eclipse.ini`?

Comment: No, I have JAVA_HOME set.

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why. Note that I got a Java error code of -1073740771 (0xc000005).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a known JVM bug in C2 compiler: [JDK-8154831](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154831).

Try adding the following JVM argument:
`-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::*`

Comment: Thanks, was looking around in many places for the solution on this one. This one worked for me. Almost tried everything. It all started after my laptop suddenly crashed. Eclipse was trying to sync all the files again to last state using the .snap files in the workspace. However nothing was working. I deleted all the .snap files, indexes and eventually the metadata folder. But after that I started getting this error. Adding the above line to eclipse.ini file worked.

Comment: Works perfectly!.. Thank you!

Comment: This error started to happen when I upgraded my java installation from 11.0.6 to 11.0.8. Looks like this solves the problem

Answer (score 7):

This is an Java issue - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154831 
 it has been fixed in 9 and backported to 8u112. 
Kindly upgrade your Java to 8u112 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html ) 
Excluding method from compilation may not be the good solution -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::*