# Often EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) errors

Tags: java, crash, jvm, crash-reports

I started to observe often crashes of JVM. Currently I even can't to compile any big Java project, because of those crashes.

During compile, JVM crashes, creates `hs_err_pid` files everywhere in the project and it causes consequent errors.

Is it possible to understand somehow, what is the reason of these crashes from those reports?

Example reports header is follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000064afd7a0, pid=16496, tid=0x00000000000010a0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x50d7a0]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000003a064800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4256, stack(0x000000003a830000,0x000000003a930000)]
```

First thought was that it is memory hardware problem, but no any error found with memory test.

What else it can be and how to trace it?

Comment: Looks like JVM bug in JIT compiler. Please show the full `hs_err` crash report.

Comment: I tried different versions of JDK (1.8.91 and 1.8.102) Can it be the bug in all of them???

Comment: Yes, it can. It might be [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663629/eclipse-exception-access-violation-crash/38669885).