# Eclipse and Intellij keeps crashing with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, crash, jvm

Update: The same problem seems to occur in Intellij as well.
My eclipse installation keeps crashing without warning. The window will just suddenly close at random points.

An error log is sometime produced. An example of this is below (the message varies)

I had a few issues with crashes during the eclipse installation. I've reinstalled java (8) and eclipse, even gone to a fresh windows install (this just changed the error messages)

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000003bd0248, pid=3780, tid=0x0000000000000718
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 8164 C1 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil$Copier.copy(Lorg/eclipse/emf/ecore/EObject;)Lorg/eclipse/emf/ecore/EObject; (139 bytes) @ 0x0000000003bd0248 [0x0000000003bcf3c0+0xe88]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000025d0800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=1816, stack(0x0000000000050000,0x0000000000150000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000000003c1

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000001dd15fb8, RCX=0x000000000000047d, RDX=0x00000001003ae698
RSP=0x000000000014df30, RBP=0x000000001f727c40, RSI=0x00000000c1668a48, RDI=0x0000000000000001
R8 =0x000000001f727c40, R9 =0x0000000000000320, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000010038d100, R14=0x000000000014de18, R15=0x00000000025d0800
RIP=0x0000000003bd0248, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010212
```

And another:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ce0c220, pid=7156, tid=0x00000000000015a0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x3c220]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000017f4b000):  JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=5536, stack(0x00000000189d0000,0x0000000018ad0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000002234fff8

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000027, RBX=0x0000000018acf968, RCX=0x000000002eca5910, RDX=0xfffffffff36aa6f0
RSP=0x0000000018aced48, RBP=0x00000000005aff00, RSI=0x000000001cd1fdc0, RDI=0x0000000021e25640
R8 =0x000000000052af00, R9 =0x0000000021fe9c00, R10=0x0000000000002000, R11=0x000000002e77b050
R12=0x00000000005aff00, R13=0x00000000000000b8, R14=0x000000001cd1fb70, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x000000006ce0c220, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206
```

The system info contains

```
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.0)

CPU:total 3 (3 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 16 model 5 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, popcnt, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8386740k(6510284k free), swap 10352820k(8395928k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 18:21:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

And a third

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000000000276703f, pid=11876, tid=0x0000000000002e68
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 32 C1 sun.misc.FDBigInteger.trimLeadingZeros()V (57 bytes) @ 0x000000000276703f [0x0000000002766f00+0x13f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
```

The workspace log contains repeated:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-04-11 18:19:39.359
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\gardi'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2017-04-11 18:40:15.939 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_121
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-04-11 18:40:39.941
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\gardi'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Contents of eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\gardi\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Update:
Tried solution from [Eclipse EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663629/eclipse-exception-access-violation-crash/38669885#38669885) with no luck.

Comment: Does http://www.memtest.org/ report any errors?

Comment: Hmm test is ongoing but a failure is happening on test 10 (modulo 20brabdom pattern) . I suspect one of the ram sticks may be faulty (4*2gb). I'll try and isolate which one is faulty and see if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Check /.metadata/.log and post logged messages
2. Navigate to a hidden directory in your Eclipse Workspace named .metadata, delete it, and start eclipse. Files in the .metadata directory seem to cause recurrent problems once Eclipse begins to crash.

If this does not help, update the question with your eclipse.ini file containts

Comment: Tried deleting ./metadata, no luck. Added contents of .ini file to question
Thanks

Comment: Please disable the line useG1GC. This garbage collection should be used in mutiprocesser env and with heap memory greater than 6GBs. Though it may not be the root cause, it is not needed here.

Comment: Tried that. 2 open attempts neither managed to get to the open stage without crashing, 1 got to workspace but crashed shortly after. . Two resulted in an access violation as before, one resulted in Internal Error (sharedRuntime.cpp:533), pid=8428, tid=0x0000000000001d04
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

Comment: Probably it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/38669885/3164160. Can you try the changes suggested here?

Comment: I just tried adding the line from the solution in the linked question. No such luck.

Comment: I downloaded and installed intellij, and that has similar issues. It must be something deeper than a problem with eclipse

Comment: Yes, this is a Windows exception. If you are not using any feature of "Java 8" you can probably, download Java 7 and try pointing your java to this version. This workaround may get you working

Comment: A similar thread i wanted to point out earlier where a driver update has solved the issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406681/jvm-crash-exception-access-violation . This would require much detailed deep dive on your side.